# perform segue with identifier wont work in swift 2

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2

I have been using this code to perform a custom segue when a user logs in to the application:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showSTPS", sender: self)

}
```

I currently have this code in my perpareForSegue (im not totally sure if i need it)

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){
            if "showSTPS" == segue.identifier {
                }
}
```

And I am getting the following error every time I try to perform the segue:

> 2015-08-31 11:56:28.998 ICEFLO[3858:651041] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not perform segue with identifier 'showSTPS'. A segue must either have a performHandler or it must override -perform.'

Any suggestions on what to do would be greatly appreciated - please note that this is for swift2/ios9

-Yogi

Comment: Please post the code for your custom segue subclass(es)

Comment: There is absolutely no code for the custom segue, the only reason I have set it to custom is that we can not use push.

Comment: Custom segues are intended for segue that use custom animations - see this tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/custom-segue-animations/

Comment: Irrelevent.. the issue is that i cant programatically perform a segue. I also don't get the option to use show for some weird reason

Comment: How are you creating the segue?

Comment: Hey rich, That article actually really helped, all i needed to do was create a custom class for the segue.. thanks

Comment: Ok, great. Strange that you weren't seeing the 'show' option tho - you shouldn't need a custom class for a vanilla segue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple segue not working in xcode 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483261/simple-segue-not-working-in-xcode-7)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Make sure that in your storyboard the segue type is not set to custom. If you set it to custom you'll need to provide your own custom segue class.

Answer (score 5):

Swift version:

```
class CustomSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {

        let src = self.sourceViewController
        let dst = self.destinationViewController
        src.navigationController?.pushViewController(dst, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to add to this answer: note that you don't call `super.perform()` within this method, otherwise you'll get the same runtime error as the OP, despite overriding the method.

Comment: @ThomasVerbeek are you saying we should call `super.perform()` or that we shouldn't? The answer still includes it.

Comment: @TashPemhiwa I'm saying you *shouldn't* call `super.perform()`. I've submitted an edit :)

Comment: what if we do not use navigationController?

Answer (score 3):

If your segue is set to "Custom", you need to override the *perform* method. You can follow [this example](http://blog.jimjh.com/a-short-tutorial-on-custom-storyboard-segues.html).

Basically create a class that inherits from UIStoryboardSegue, like this:

MyCustomSegue.h

```
@interface MyCustomSegue : UIStoryboardSegue
@end
```

MyCustomSegue.m

```
@implementation MyCustomSegue
- (void) perform {
    UIViewController *src = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *dst = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;

    [src.navigationController pushViewController:dst animated:YES];
}
@end
```

I think this code could work for you.

Comment: The OP asked for a swift 2 solution -1

Comment: This solution fixes the exact error he is having. I'll add a swift2 adaptation of my answer as soon as I have one implemented (i'm working with objC only at the moment). This answer fixes the problem anyway

Answer (score 1):

do NOT call super...

```
class CustomSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {
        // super.perform() NOOO or crash!
        let src = self.sourceViewController
        let dst = self.destinationViewController
        src.navigationController?.pushViewController(dst, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: what if we are not using navigationController