# Simple segue not working in xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

Simple segue that has worked for months performed with this command:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ExpirationWarningSegue" sender:self];
```

now yields this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not perform segue
>   with identifier 'ExpirationWarningSegue'. A segue must either have a
>   performHandler or it must override -perform.'

What? It's a segue. I command-drag from one `UIViewController` to another in the storyboard. I'm not writing code for this. The segue is defined in the storyboard with this exact identifier.

Why does this happen now that I have upgraded to xcode 7 when it used to work just fine?

Comment: Possibility: In Interface Builder, it's set as custom, and that's why it's asking you to override/have perform/performHandler... Change it to whatever you want, but not custom.

Comment: I don't understand the down votes here. It's a legitmate question. This code worked just fine until xcode 7 / ios 9 started to reject it. Yes, I was incorrectly using a custom segue - that is the answer to the problem. But the error message did not explain this, in my opinion, and Apple suddenly decided to reject this structure.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but a quick search on Google with " A segue must either have a performHandler or it must override perform." would have point out the issue. Well, in other hand matt's answer is quite better than the one found there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32309909/perform-segue-with-identifier-wont-work-in-swift-2

Comment: I googled that many times. As I'm sure you know, search engines do not deliver the same set of results to all people, and that result was not delivered to me. Had it been, my question would never have been asked.

Comment: Well, what I'm saying, is that people finding an answer like the one I linked, may have downvoted your question. I won't say they did good or bad, I'm just trying to explain possibly (nothing is sure) why you may have been downvoted.

Comment: OK. Thanks. And thanks also for your original answer. It really helped me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message tells you exactly what the problem is:

> 'Could not perform segue with identifier 'ExpirationWarningSegue'. A segue must either have a performHandler or it must override -perform.'

This is a custom segue. Therefore it must implement `perform`.

A cool feature of Xcode 7 / iOS 9 is that you can use a custom segue even where you have already specified a push (show) segue or a present (modal) segue. In that case, your `perform` must call `super` to get the original behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What you call 'cool' I call a pain in the neck. I appreciate response, however. Thank you!

Comment: BTW, I respectfully disagree that the error message tells me exactly what the problem is. The problem is that I was incorrectly using a custom segue without using a performHandler. The error message makes no reference to a custom segue, which is at the heart of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

See my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32309909/perform-segue-with-identifier-wont-work-in-swift-2/33895418#33895418). It is a simple custom segue implementation in  objC. Porting it to swift is trivial.